# Calling a method within the same class

Tags: c#, methods

I am working on a simple program to generate an array of values and perform some basic computations on them. I am having problems calling my "Mean" and "Median" methods from the Main method. I've attached the compiler error below. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class arraymod
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] values;
            values = new int[10];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                values[i] = rand.Next(1,20);
            }

            Array.Sort(values);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", values.Min());
            Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", values.Max());
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", values.Sum());
            Console.WriteLine("Mean: {0}", values.Mean()); //program fails here
            Console.WriteLine("Median: {0}", values.Median());
        }
        public int Mean(int[] arr)
        {
            int valuesMean = arr.Sum()/arr.Count();
            return valuesMean;
        }
        public int Median(int[] arr)
        {
            int valuesMedian = (arr.Max()+ arr.Min())/2;
            return valuesMedian;
        }
    }
}
```

arraymod.cs(29,42):

> error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition   for
>   'Mean' and no extension method 'Mean' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or   an assembly reference?)

Comment: What do you mean by `Mean()` method? As error said, there is no method of `Array` called that. Have you try to write an extension method for `Array`? Then read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Linq already has the [`Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.100).aspx) method that is the same as mean.  Also since you already calculate the min and max to write to the console, why not store those in variables instead and just calculate the median from them instead of running `Max` and `Min` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a extension method. You need to make methods static and call them:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class arraymod
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int[] values;
        values = new int[ 10 ];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            values[ i ] = rand.Next( 1 , 20 );
        }

        Array.Sort( values );
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( values[ i ] );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "Min: {0}" , values.Min() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Max: {0}" , values.Max() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Sum: {0}" , values.Sum() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Mean: {0}" , Mean( values ) ); //call
        Console.WriteLine( "Median: {0}" , Median( values ) );//call
    }
    //make method "Mean" static
    public static int Mean( int[] arr )
    {
        int valuesMean = arr.Sum() / arr.Count();
        return valuesMean;
    }
    //make method "Median" static
    public static int Median( int[] arr )
    {
        int valuesMedian = ( arr.Max() + arr.Min() ) / 2;
        return valuesMedian;
    }
}
}
```

Or use extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
static class arraymod
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int[] values;
        values = new int[ 10 ];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            values[ i ] = rand.Next( 1 , 20 );
        }

        Array.Sort( values );
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( values[ i ] );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "Min: {0}" , values.Min() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Max: {0}" , values.Max() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Sum: {0}" , values.Sum() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Mean: {0}" , values.Mean() ); //call
        Console.WriteLine( "Median: {0}" , values.Median() );//call
    }
    //use extension method
    public static int Mean( this int[] arr )
    {
        int valuesMean = arr.Sum() / arr.Count();
        return valuesMean;
    }
    //use extension method
    public static int Median( this int[] arr )
    {
        int valuesMedian = ( arr.Max() + arr.Min() ) / 2;
        return valuesMedian;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1) You need to call `Mean(values)` and `Median(values)`

2) Main is a static method whereas Mean and Median are instance methods. Either create an instance of arraymod and call them:

```
var inst = new arraymod();
int mean = inst.Mean(values);
int median = inst.Median(values);
```

or alternatively, make the methods static:

```
public static int Mean(int[] arr)
public static int Median(int[] arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Mean()` on array instance. If that mean calculation is different from LINQ `Average` does, define an extension method for it.
Example:

```
static int Mean(this int[] arr)
{
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: Should note that the class containing the method has to be static for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that if you want extension methods you need to use the key word `this` before the first parameter, make the method static, and put the method into a static class.

```
static class arraymod
{
    public static int Mean(int[] arr)
    {
        int valuesMean = arr.Sum()/arr.Count();
        return valuesMean;
    }

    public static int Median(int[] arr)
    {
        int valuesMedian = (arr.Max()+ arr.Min())/2;
        return valuesMedian;
    }
}
```

Personally I wouldn't bother with creating a `Mean` method since `Average` already does the same thing.  And you can make the code more efficient by calculating everything in one loop versus multiple Linq calls that will each iterate the array separately.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] values;
    values = new int[10];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        values[i] = rand.Next(1,20);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int max = int.MinValue;
    int min = int.MaxValue;
    Array.Sort(values);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sum += values[i];
        if(values[i] < min)
        {
            min = values[i];
        }

        if(values[i] > max)
        {
            max = values[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", min);
    Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", max);
    Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", sum);
    Console.WriteLine("Mean: {0}", sum/values.Length); 
    Console.WriteLine("Median: {0}", (min + max)/2);
}
```

Also note that the calculations for mean and median use integer division which will result in truncation.